# A single DTO class with multiple classes inside

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-access-layer, dto, bll

a simple question about DTO, I have a DTO class Cars, and some others subclasses of cars models inside it.

```
    public class Cars
{
    public Ferrari FerrariModel { get; set; }
    public Porshe PorsheModel {get; set; }
    public Mustang MustangModel { get; set; }
}
    public class Ferrari
{  
    public string collor{ get; set; }
    public int year{ get; set; }
    public double price{ get; set; }
}
```

and Porshe and Mustang are exactly the same Ferrari. The problem is I do not know how to proceed now. I try something like that

```
Cars cars = new Cars();
FerrariModel fm = new FerrariModel();
cars.FerrariModel.collor = txtCollor.Text;
```

And it is not working, as I get the follow error in the cars.FerrariModel.collor -> "Object reference not set paragraph An Instance of hum object . the hum object declaration".
I must confess I dont even know it "is possible" or if I am "inventing prograiming", so any help woulb be greatfull.

1. why use only a single class? Because a need to pass a single DTO in parameters: save(Cars car); update(Cars car)
2. using a second separeted class would force me to "overload" the method: save(Cars car); save(Ferrari ferrari);
3. if I use a single class (without Ferrari, Porshe and Mustang) the program work but I have lots of variables in my InteliSense, over 50.

Thank you.

Comment: The code is doing too many things which end up breaking **[Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)**. If Models have similar properties, they can inherit from an **interface** or a **abstract** class. Then you can then use **Generic List**.

Comment: Thank you, I still a begginer and I do not know much about interfaces and abstract classes, I am studying Generic Lists lately, and even I using this method just like a Transfer data object, do you thing it is "heavy" ? Because I really do no want to have lots of methods for lots of operation that do almost the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your `fm` instance to your `Cars.FerarriModel` property.

```
Cars cars = new Cars();
FerrariModel fm = new FerrariModel();
cars.FerrariModel = fm;
cars.FerrariModel.collor = txtCollor.Text;
```

Or even just:

```
Cars cars = new Cars();
cars.FerrariModel = new FerrariModel() { collor = txtCollor.Text };
```

Comment: Dude! I just cant believe it really worked! Haha I thougt you guys would'n even understand the "crazy question" haha!!! Really thank you man! I wasted lots of day to do that and I would never get that alone, really thank you!!!

Comment: No problems. Have a read of your exception messages - it tells you that one of your references are not set. This usually points to chained statements (or previously assigned variables) being null (due to not being instantiated yet). Further, if you can get a hold of your exception detail within the debugger or logger then you'll see that the stack trace should be pointing you directly to the offending line of code.